# Get all records from 2 columns, starting from specific row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gspread

**Set-up**

Via gspread I have access to a Google sheet containing data.

Normally, I use `df = pd.DataFrame(wsheet.get_all_records())` to dump all data into a pandas dataframe.

---

**Issue**

I only need the data of 5 specific sequential columns, i.e. all columns including and between for example column 1 and 5 of the Google sheet.

Moreover, I only need the data starting from the 5th row in the Google sheet.

I've tried my regular `df = pd.DataFrame(wsheet.get_all_records())` and then drop columns and rows in pandas. However, I think due to the markup I use in the first 4 rows in the Google sheet, the resulting dataframe has some oddities – adjusting in pandas gives strange results.

---

**Question**

Given the markup, I suspect it's easier to just dump all data incl. and between column 1 and 5 in a dataframe, starting from row 5.

But how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values from the columns "A" and "E" after the row 5 from the Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Modification points:

- In this modification, at first, the values are retrieved with `get_all_values()` as a slice. And the retrieved values are processed and convert it to the dataframe.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows. In this case, it supposes that `wsheet` can be used.

##### From:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(wsheet.get_all_records())
```

##### To:

```
v = [[e[0], e[4]] for e in wsheet.get_all_values()]
df = pd.DataFrame(v[4:], columns=v[0])
```

- In this case, `df` is the values retrieved the columns "A" and "E" after the row 5.

#### Reference:

- [get_all_values()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.get_all_values)

### Added:

If you want to retrieve the values from **the columns "A" to "E"** after the row 5 from the Google Spreadsheet, how about the following modification?

##### From:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(wsheet.get_all_records())
```

##### To:

```
v = [e[0:5] for e in wsheet.get_all_values()]
df = pd.DataFrame(v[4:], columns=v[0])
```

Comment: Flawless again! Your 'Added' code was the one I needed :-)

Comment: @LucSpan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.